# For-loops and if-statements on cross referenced sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got 5 sheets - 1 main sheet and 4 sheets for data. The 4 sheets hold a column of W's and L's, and the main sheet has 8 cells to keep track of these - one cell for each # of W's and # of L's. I'm trying to do so with the following script and then calling the methods in the respective cells of the main sheet.

```
function totalWins(data) {
  var win = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i = + 1) {
    if(data[i][0] = "W") {
      win = win + 1;
    }
  }
  return win;
}

function totalLosses(data) {
  var loss = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i = + 1) {
    if(data[i][0] = "L") {
      loss = loss + 1;
    }
  }
  return loss;
}
```

I get the `Internal error executing the custom function.` error, which means the code takes longer than 30 seconds to run through the column (n = 100) in one of the four sheets. I really can't figure out why it does this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increment `i`. Without you assign `+1` to `i` and the loop takes only the first two values and loops forever with `i === 1`.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 1) {
//                                   ^
```

or a bit shorter

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
```

---

As mentioned in the comments by [TheWizEd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3656739/thewized), you assign a value if the `if` statement, where you should compare the value

```
if (data[i][0] === "W") {
//             ^^         strict comparison
```

Comment: Alright, so with this change the methods actually run, but they both return 100 now. There are quite a lot of empty cells in the range I'm looping through - could that be the issue? Or do you have any other suggestions? :-)

Comment: one hundred items is close to nothing. without knowing more, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Shouldn't if(data[i][0] = "W") be if(data[i][0] == "W")?  Same for "L".

Comment: Doesn't change anything it seems @TheWizEd

Comment: Check "data" using Logger.log(data); or Logger.log(data.length);

Answer (score 0):

You placed `+` at wrong place in your code

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i = + 1) {
//                                   ^
                                     |____ This makes acts as `+` sign
```

So in this case you're not actually incrementing your index so you loop keep on running

change to this

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
//                                 ^
                                   |_____  This acts as `addition`
```

Or simply use `i++`

Comment: I changed this and the ```win = win + 1;``` to ```win++;```. Now the methods run, but both return 0. There are quite a lot of empty cells in the range I'm looping through - could that be the issue? Or do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @simonbrage Why you're changing `win = win + 1` to `win += 1` both are same only

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by changing the counters `win = win + 1` and `loss = loss + 1` to `win +=1` and `loss +=1`. Also with the above increments.

Comment: changing `win = win + 1` to `win += 1` same for loss will not make any difference

Comment: @CodeManiac Well, it didn't work before, and it does work now. I'm not the one if you want to know why xD